# How to handle logic in a subscribe callback?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm working on an application which displays table data fetched thru a http call. The problem I'm running into is that there's a lot of logic in my subscribe callbacks. How can I handle this in a better way?

The code below is from a component which displays a table with filters, which also has a 5 second polling running (started by this.pollingHandler()).

some info about the code below:

- carId is initially fetched from a path variable
- this.loading is used to display a loading message
- this.rows = data shown in the table
- calling pollingHandler() starts polling
- this.resetFilterForm() resets all the filters in the form

```
fetchTableData(carId:string): void {
    this.resetFilterForm();
    this.carService.getcar(carId)
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
        .subscribe({
            next: (response: Car) => {
                this.car = response;
                this.carId = response.carId;
                this.rows = response.carData;
                this.pollingHandler();
                this.loading = false;
            },
            error: (response) => {
                this.rows = [];
                this.loading = false;
                this.notificationUtilService.addErrorToastNotification(response?.error?.message ?? "Error getting car data")
            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid callback hell, you can define your callback functions outside of the subscribe call.

```js
  setData = (response: Car) => {
    this.car = response;
    this.carId = response.carId;
    this.rows = response.carData;
    this.pollingHandler();
    this.loading = false;
  };

  handleError = (response: any) => {
    this.rows = [];
    this.loading = false;
    this.notificationUtilService.addErrorToastNotification(
      response?.error?.message ?? 'Error getting car data'
    );
  };

  fetchTableData(carId: string): void {
    this.resetFilterForm();
    this.carService.getcar(carId).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe({
      next: this.setData,
      error: this.handleError,
    });
  }
```